# How to declare keyword variable in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, variables

I am a new iOS programming. I am creating a sample app which get data and set data using Firestore. For the collection contains some documents which and named those properties like `extension`... So in programming I need to create variable with that name `extension` in order to set data to Firestore but Xcode is warning me that I don't have to declare that variable name.

I have been trying to figure it out but not work. So, I decided to ask my own question if there any technique to delacre variable name which is warning by Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var `extension`: String?
var username: String?

init(`extension`: String, username: String) {
    self.`extension` = `extension`
    self.username = username
}
```

I think this will work by using ``` `` ```.

Comment: Oh.. this is great